# how to protect Symfony login against timing attacks?

Tags: php, symfony, security, hash

We have a pretty standard Symfony2 application. There's a provider, a password encoder an so on. The passwords are hashed with pretty large hashing cost.

In other words - when someone tries to log in (not necessarily with correct password) - it is obvious when there's a real user to check the hash and when it isn't. In the second case it's much quicker - no user - no need to hash etc.

So it's easy to know **if a particular email is registered in our app**.

Is there any built-in mechanism in Symfony to prevent this sort of leak? Or any established best practice?

**UPD in response to the first answers:**
How to handle this in general is more or less clear, the question is how we can do it without much pain within Symfony's security framework.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into consideration that if the user doesn't exist, but you still want to calculate a hash to fool an attacker trying to enumerate user accounts, there will be no password to be hashed, so you have two options (there can be more, but right now I only thought about these two):

1._ Have a hardcoded password that will be hashed when a user doesn't exist.

2._ Use a pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) to generate a random password, which will be the one that you'll hash (we don't really care abount unpredictability here, so there's no need to use cryptographically secure one).

The problem with the first attempt is that, since you're always hashing the same password, the response times when the users don't exist will be pretty consistent, so even if the attacker doesn't see an evident faster response when the user doesn't exist, he can notice that there's an average response time for these scenarios. The second attempt has a similar problem, but here, you're hashing a random password AND generating that random password, so you're adding overhead and the response is highly likely to always take a longer amount of time, than when just authenticating an existing user, so an attacker can also notice the pattern.

What you could do is to add a random noise to every request (both for existing and nonexistent users), where you'll add a random delay of a few milliseconds. By doing this, you can use a fixed password for nonexistent users, and even when you'll be calculating the same hash for nonexistent users, that random noise will make it harder for an attacker to know if it's a real or fake login attempt.

Comment: Actually, i think that the first option doesn't have the problem you mentioned as we could use some fixed-time hashing function like the one suggested in the another answer. That is the way forward, or, as we did in another projet, we just allocate fixed time for auth procedure and just sleep if has taken less than that. This is all good, but my question is if we have any graceful/recommended/built-in way to do this thing in Symfony's security framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP built in function [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). From the documentation:

> Verifies that the given hash matches the given password.

Note that password_hash() returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

> 

This function is safe against timing attacks.

If you use symfony password encoder, it has method `isPasswordValid`, which internally uses this function, so you don't need to worry about timing attack: [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/BCryptPasswordEncoder.php)

Comment: yes, we do use this function. But if someone enters _not_existing_ email - the framework (I suppose) doesn't attempt to compare passwords making the page load noticeably quiker. So it's easy to say if the mail exists in our database or not. That's the problem.